With web page crashes, how does one determine if the client browser is crashing vs. the server side?
We self-host an internal website for colleagues that renders lots of data/ images.
We suspect the internal website (hosted in AWS) is under provisioned or has other bad practices and is the root cause of web pages crashes.
However, some say it may simply be Chrome being overwhelmed with the amount of data/ rendering images/ charts.
We can monitor and analyze the former (AWS instances) of course -- but is there a clear-cut way to see if the Browser is also being overwhelmed or not?
I suspect not, but can't be certain.
I.e. if a tab with 10 charts hangs up, says "unresponsive, kill task' -- is there a quick way to determine if the browser is causing the client-machine to run of memory? Yes you can monitor use Task Manager/ Activity Monitor real time, but what exactly are you looking for?
Would other tabs still working be counter-evidence to this? ... Not exactly sure how to systematically monitor at the browser end.

If the browser is unresponsive then that implies pretty strongly to me that the problem is client-side.  If it was waiting on something from the server then it wouldn't be unresponsive, it would just be waiting.

Review what options Chrome has for debugging unresponsive tabs, e.g. the --enable-logging startup option.
